# create file shell script

Tags: linux, shell

I am new to shell scripting in Linux and I am trying to take data from the keyboard and then append the data passed in to a file. Pretty straight forward but I am getting an error when I try to create the file. The error says "you do not have permission to create this file".

I first do a check to make sure the file exists. If it exists, append to the end of the file. If not, create the file. What am I doing wrong?

Thank you!

P.S. In this case, I do not have the file created yet

```
#!/bin/sh                                                                                                                            

echo "Please enter your first name";
read first
echo "Please enter your last name";
read last

combine=":$first $last"
file="/testFile.dat"

if [ -f "$file" ]
then
echo "$file found."
echo $combine >> $file
else
echo "$file not found. Will create the file and add entry now."
touch $file
$combine >> $file
fi
```

Comment: Sounds like your problem is `you do not have permission to create this file`.  Linux file systems do not let arbitrary users read or write to arbitrary locations.  Try changing `file="/testFile.dat"` to `file="~/testFile.dat"`, which will put the file in your home dir.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to write to the file `/testFile.dat` which is located in the root directory `/`. It is highly likely that as a regular user you would not have write permissions for creating such a file.

But what you wanted I'm guessing is to create the `testfile.dat` in the current directory.

Replace the following line:

```
file="/testFile.dat"
```

with:

```
file="./testFile.dat"
```

Comment: That makes sense. What a silly mistake on my part :) Thank you! Will accept

Answer (score 3):

You are creating the file at the root. Try `file="~/testFile.dat"` to create the file in your home or just `file="./testFile.dat"` to create it in the current directory.